# Add existing display menu item to user favorites

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, x++

Based on [this Code](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axsolutionsmonkey/archive/2009/10/23/add-all-role-centers-to-ax-client-favorites-for-demo-purpose) I've build the basics of a function to give each user a predefined set of favorites.

However this particular code creates a new AOT element for each favorite of each user. I would like to configure the menu items manually and simply distribute them with the script.

**How can I (in X++) get a reference to an existing `\Menu Items\Display` node and add that to an object of the `Menu` class?**

This is what I have so far:

```
MyFavorites obj = new MyFavorites();
Menu menuNode;

MenuFunction mf;
TreeNode treeNode;

info("Applying favorites...");

menuNode = obj.getOrCreateRoot();
if (menuNode == null) return;

treeNode = menuNode.AOTfindChild("Administrator");
if (!treeNode)
{
    menuNode.addSubmenu("Administrator");
    treeNode = menuNode.AOTfindChild("Administrator");
    info("Created submenu");
}
else info("Found submenu");

menuNode = treeNode;

// Here I need help. I don't want to recreate all these AOT nodes every time the script is run.
mf = new MenuFunction("Fav_AllUsers",MenuItemType::Display);
mf.AOTsave();

menuNode.addMenuitem(mf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick job I wrote that adds "SalesTable" menu to your favorites.

[Also here's a link that shows how to copy favorites between users](http://dynamics-ax-live.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-copy-favorites-from-one-user-to.html)

A thing to note is the table `SysPersonalization`, which stores a blob of the data so you'll have to use either the object `UserMenuList`, `Menu`, or that table to accomplish what you want. This should get you started though.

```
static void Job4(Args _args)
{
    TreeNode                treeNode;
    TreeNode                menuToAdd = TreeNode::findNode(@"\Menu Items\Display\SalesTable");
    TreeNodeIterator        iterator;
    UserMenuList            userMenu;
    Menu                    menuNode;


    treeNode = infolog.userNode();
    iterator = treeNode.AOTiterator();
    treeNode = iterator.next();
    if (treeNode)
    {
        userMenu = treeNode;

        // find 'My Favorites' user menu; 
        treeNode = userMenu.AOTfindChild("@SYS95713");

        // Note menuNode is a different object than userMenu
        menuNode = treeNode;

        menuNode.addMenuitem(menuToAdd);
    }    
}
```